# How to remove characters from console output in C

Tags: c, optimization, console, character, output

**Code1:**

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    unsigned short i, j, k;
    for (i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        k = i * 4 + 4;

        for (j = k - 4; j < k; j++)
            printf("%hu ", j);

        putchar('\n');
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**Output of Code1:**

```
0 1 2 3 
4 5 6 7
```

**Remarks of Code1:**

1. Space after **3** and **7**
2. Newline after **7** *(Stackoverflow has removed it)*

**Code2:**

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    unsigned short i, j, k;
    for (i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        k = i * 4 + 4;
        for (j = k - 4; j < k; j++)
        {
            printf("%hu", j);

            if (j + 1 != k) putchar(' ');
        }

        if (i + 1 != 2) putchar('\n');
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**Output of Code2:**

```
0 1 2 3
4 5 6 7
```

**Remarks of Code2:**

1. No space after **3** and **7**
2. No newline after **7**

**Additional remark of Code2:**

The problem of **Code2** is that the algorithm always compares two values in the **if** blocks and so **Code2** is not efficient. I want to use **Code1** and change these:

**Code3**

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    unsigned short i, j, k;
    for (i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        k = i * 4 + 4;

        for (j = k - 4; j < k; j++)
            printf("%hu ", j);

        printf("\b\n");
    }

    putchar('\b');
    return 0;
}
```

These do not show the same output of **Code2** because **\b** does not erase anything.

**My question:**

Is there any standard way to do so what I've tried in **Code3**?

**Remark of my question:**

1. I have searched the internet but have not determined the solution.
2. Edit the question if it is not clear.

**Edit:** *I don't know why my question is not useful or constructive. Though the above is an arbitrary small example, but performance might be an issue when processing very large amount of data. I thought that the way of removing character from console output might improve performance and there might be a specific way to do so. That's why I've asked the question. I could write the following codes in the answers. Now I've known via comments that removing character from console output is not possible because it is implementation dependent.*

Comment: The question is not clear: do you aim for the output of code 2 ? If so why not organize the code in a way where you don't place '\n' and space characters you don't need there in the first place ?

Comment: Lesson 1: `'\b'` is just a byte sent to your stdout. If your stdout happens to go to a terminal, the terminal may respond by moving the caret backward (just like it responds to `'\t'` by moving the caret forward some number of times). Or the terminal may not. It depends on the implementation.  Lesson 2: please do not prematurely optimize! The process of outputting characters to terminal DWARFS any time you could possibly spend in `if`s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual approach to this is to treat either the first or the last `printf` as a special case (outside of the loop):

```
for(ii=0; ii<2; ii++) {
  jj = 0;
  printf("%d", jj);      // first number printed without space.
  for(jj=1; jj<4; jj++) {
    printf(" %d", jj);   // include the space before the number printed
  }
  if(ii<2-1) printf("\n");
}
```

Obviously I simplified how the loops are constructed and what is printed - for simplicity. You could make the first `printf` statement

```
printf("\n%d", jj);
```

then you have a newline at the start of your output (often a good thing) and then you don't need the `if` statement later - you just don't have a newline printed at the end of the line (because it will be printed at the start...)

There are marginally more efficient ways of doing this that would involve no `if` statements at all - but these all come at the expense of less readable code. For example, here is a "no loop unrolling and no additional if statements" version of the code:

http://codepad.org/01qPPtee

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void) {
int ii, jj;
   ii = 0;
   while(1) {
      jj = 0;
      while(1) {
        printf("%d", jj);   // include the space before the number printed
        jj++;
        if(jj<4) printf("."); else break;
      }
      ii++;
      if(ii<2) printf("*\n"); else break;
    }
return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
0.1.2.3*
0.1.2.3
```

Basically I have taken the functionality of the `for` loop and made it explicit; I also use a `.` rather than a  and `"*\n"` rather than `"\n"` to show in the printout that things behave as expected.

It does what you asked without extra evaluation of the condition. Is it more readable? Not really...

Comment: Your second code is efficient though less readable. I could make all the codes of the answers to my question. I want to know if there is any standard way to remove the last character from the console output what I have tried in **Code3**?

Comment: @arnobpl -  Unfortunately "removing the character from console output" is implementation dependent - so there is no guaranteed "backspace and delete". I suspect this is a hangover from the days of teletypes - once the character was on paper you could backspace to overwrite, but you could not delete it. See Arkadiy 's comment. You might be interested in the question you inspired: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20428158/putting-a-composite-statement-in-the-condition-of-a-for-loop

Answer (score 0):

If it really bothers you, you can unroll your loops a little so that you treat the last item as a special case:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    unsigned short i, j, k;
    for (i = 0; i < 1; i++)
    {
        k = i * 4 + 4;
        for (j = k - 4; j < k - 1; j++)
        {
            printf("%hu ", j);
        }
        printf("%hu\n", j);
    }

    k = i * 4 + 4;
    for (j = k - 4; j < k - 1; j++)
    {
        printf("%hu ", j);
    }
    printf("%hu", j);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your code is efficient but the code is larger. Is not there any standard way just to remove the last character from console output what I have tried in **Code3**?

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    unsigned short num = 0, to=8;

    while(num < to){
        printf("%hu", num++);
        if(num < to)
            putchar(num % 4 == 0 ? '\n' : ' ');
    }
#if 0
    do{
        printf("%hu", num++);
    }while(num < to && putchar(num % 4 == 0 ? '\n' : ' '));
#endif
    return 0 ;
}
```

Comment: I think it would not be said to be a standard way it So if you how to write like a comment to say that you find out whether the last value is because the overlap.

Answer (score 0):

Well, to try to answer your question, here's how I would do it:

```
for (i = k = 0; i < 2; i++){
  if (i > 0) printf("\n");
  for (j = 0; j < 4; j++, k++){
    if (j > 0) printf(" ");
    printf("%d", k);
  }
}
```

I do it this way because I want to be sure every line but the first starts with a `\n`, and every item is separated by a space from the one before it.
Also, I do not want the row and column position to be intimately tied to the content of what is being printed.

In terms of performance, keep in mind that these `if` statements cost about 1 cycle, while each character printed costs at least hundreds if not thousands. `printf` goes through many layers of system calls to interpret its format string, build a buffer, send the buffer to the system I/O routines, which then cause repainting and scrolling of the console window. Get the idea?

DO NOT WORRY about performance unless you know you have a problem.
Then, don't guess. Use a diagnostic. [*Here's what I do.*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/378024/23771)