# Putting a composite statement in the condition of a for loop

Tags: c, for-loop

I have a contrived example to demonstrate the request for a specific functionality - I wonder if anyone has a clever trick to do this.

The following is a problem one encounters quite frequently:

"Print a series of numbers; print a space between them, and a carriage return (but no space) at the end.

The obvious solution is to make the last (or first) statement a special case. I was pondering ways to make this more efficient/compact.

**brute force:**

```
for(ii=0; ii<4; ii++) {
  printf("%d", ii);
  if(ii<3) printf(" "); else printf("\n");
}
```

Note that this involves **two** evaluations of a condition.

**unrolling:**

```
for(ii=0; ii<3; ii++) {
  printf("%d ", ii):
}
printf("%d\n", ii);
```

Leverages the fact that `ii` will be incremented one last time as we leave the loop.

**functionality I would like**

```
ii = 0;
while(1) {
  printf("%d", ii);
  ii++;
  if(ii<3) printf(" "); 
  else {printf("\n"); break;}
}
```

And I was wondering if it's possible to make this work inside the `for` statement. I tinkered a bit, and found that the following works (somewhat to my surprise... it did need the parentheses, and it quite unreadable between the `?:` and the `,` operators - see http://codepad.org/wFa2YwCg):

```
for(ii=0; (ii<3)?(printf("%d ",ii),1):(printf("%d\n",ii),0);ii++);
```

I am essentially turning the `evaluate this condition` part of the for loop into a `execute this statement for most of the loop, and this other one for the last pass` statement.

I was wondering if there is a better way to do this - both efficient, and readable?

Comment: If you are just unrolling it, in order to account for the extra `ii` that is printed, you could just do: `for(ii=0; ii<2; ii++)` so it prints `0 1 2` instead of upto `3`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[In many ways this question should be closed as it's opinion based.]

This problem crops up often. I always opt for a solution that minimises the instructions in the iterative part.

```
{ /*don't pollute the outer scope with ii*/
    int ii;
    for (ii = 0; ii < 3; ++ii/*I've always preferred this to ii++*/) {
        printf("%d ", ii);
    }
    printf("%d\n", ii);
}
```

Ternaries, `if` statements *etc.* just obfuscate things. In my opinion.

Comment: This is my "unrolled" version of code. I am specifically asking for a construct inside the `for` loop that executes something different on the last iteration. I realize that may be a "can we do badly what could be done well" type of question - but I'm curious if there is a trick I'm missing.

Comment: @Floris: Indeed it largely is excepting that I scope the whole thing. You're not missing any other trick I assure you: you can't shorten `printf` any further.

Comment: I like the use of braces to create a local instance of `ii`. I am not asking for an "opinion" - I am asking for a very specific construct that puts a certain functionality inside the `for` loop condition. "Efficient" is objective - only one condition evaluated per iteration of the loop; I suppose you can argue that "readable" is somewhat subjective, but my current "solution" clearly fails the readability test...

Answer (score 1):

"Brute force" and ternary condition solution have the same complexity, but the second one is less "readable".

You can do a simple method print:

```
 void print() {
    int i = 0;
    for(i=0; i != size - 1; ++i) {
      printf("%i ",i);
    }
    printf("%i\n", i);
 }
```

I think it is efficient and readable too.
In this way you reduce [**cyclomatic complexity**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclomatic_complexity) of your alghotitm.

Comment: What you write is really equivalent to my "unrolled" code (but you have a `!=` where I use a `<` condition). I know that works - I was hoping for something else.

Comment: @Floris infact is the way I prefer, a simple cicle with no condition (=> no cyclomatic complexity) generalizing cicle with "size".

Comment: @TonyHopkinson can you expand on your comment? I don't understand.

Comment: @TonyHopkinson I'm still puzzling over your comment. See http://codepad.org/O988cB0p - this works OK if size==1. I suppose it would fail if size==0. But that was not my question.

Comment: well you know I put that unnecessary test in my answer. You didn't hence the comment. :(

Answer (score 1):

I have used the following type of construct for this situation.  It is not more efficient (still has a condition at each iteration), but I like it because it results in a single `printf`:

```
char *sep = " ";
for(ii=0; ii<4; ii++) {
  if ( ii == 3 )
    sep = "\n";
  printf( "%d%s", ii, sep );
}
```

Comment: This gets closer to what I think I was looking for. It still involves the evaluation of two if statements.

Comment: I would use `char sep=' ';` etc. if I was going to use this. But I can't figure out how to cram it into the `for` condition as I would like.

Comment: @Bathsheba - that is magnanimous of you.

Comment: @Floris it really reflects the opinion-based nature of this topic

Answer (score 1):

For both readability and performance, I think the following code can be used:

```
for (ii = 0;; ii++)
{
    printf("%d", ii);
    (ii < 3) ? (putchar(' ')) : ({ putchar('\n'); break; });
}
```

Actually, the above code is similar to your last code. It is readable, and it still has one conditional evaluation in each increment.

Comment: I agree that this is a "slightly more readable" version of my last (dense and "write-once, read-never") version of this loop. I like the way that starting with a `for` still announces "this is a loop that will terminate at some point" - but you have to read to the end to figure out how it terminates. I like it enough to give it a vote - not enough to accept it as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
int numberoftimes = 4

if numberoftimes > 1
{
  for(ii=0; ii<numberoftimes - 1; ii++) 
  {
    printf("%d ", ii);
  }
}
printf("%d\n", numberoftimes - 1);
```

Either you test every time in the loop, or you test once first...

Comment: I don't think this needs the extra test. The inner loop will not execute if the condition fails at the first iteration.

Comment: Well spotted @Floris, glad to see one of us is still awake. :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way that requires a separate initialization pass, but that has a slightly cleaner `for` loop.  Array `sepsarray` holds the separators you want (in this example, commas so you can see them).  The last element of `sepsarray` is followed by a `'\0'` that terminates the loop.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAXNUM 5
  //print up to this 

void main() {
  char sepsarray[256] = {0}; //256=arbitrary max size
  int i;
  char *seps=sepsarray;

  for(i=0;i<MAXNUM;++i) sepsarray[i]=',';   //fill in the separators
  sepsarray[i]='\n';    //the last separator

  for(i=0; printf("%d%c",i,*seps++),*seps; i++) /* pretend to do nothing */ ;
}
```

Output:

```
0,1,2,3,4,5
```

Hardly IOCCC material, but hey... :)