# Loop Structure: FOR in C

Tags: c, loops, for-loop

Code:

```
int main()
{
   int i;
   char p[]="Hello",b[]="World!";
   for (i = 0; *p != '\0' ; i++, p+1); //what does the p+1 after ,
   printf("%s%s",p,b);
   return 0;
}
```

My question is how does exactly for loop behaves, because this program never ends, but if I write

```
for(i=0; *p != '\0'; i++, printf("hi")); //this prints out hi
```

Comment: You don't assign to `p`, you add 1 to the value and then discard it. You probably meant `p += 1` or `p++`.

Comment: Of course, because you never alter `p`.

Comment: Why do you have a variable `i` that you don't use for anything?

Comment: @Kninnug `p` is not a modifiable l-value. You can't assign to it.

Comment: Note that you generally need a newline after a `printf()` to force the output to appear.  It must work slightly differently on Windows because we see endless Windows-based C programs without the newlines, but those simply don't transfer to Unix sanely.

Comment: .. because you cannot alter p. p is not am lvalue.. Nothing is inceremented; `p+1` i just an expession like any other.

Comment: This is a final exam exercise from my collage and we have to say what it does...

Comment: @SebastianC Well it does absolutely nothing useful - you get an infinite loop. It keeps incrementing `i` and computing `p+1` for nothing.

Comment: And for loop? everything i put after i++ with comas will work? Never saw that.

Comment: @FilipeGonçalves Ah, yes, I was a little quick with that comment. The real problem stands: the condition `*p != 0` never changes because `p` never changes.

Comment: Yes, the comma operator evaluates its left operand, throws away the result, and then evaluates the right operand (which is the final result of the expression). See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator

Comment: Well that's were the answers i was looking for, thanks filipe!

Comment: Yes the comma operator is an interesting one. Basically, when you have two statements separated by a comma, the first statement is evaluated and returned, then the next one is evaluated and discarded.  So `x=1; y=2; z = x,y;` will result in `z=1`. You can do some funny things with that - see for example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20428158/putting-a-composite-statement-in-the-condition-of-a-for-loop . Note - this seems in contradiction with what I thought (see @FilipeGonçalves's link) - which is that the _right most expression_ is the one that is returned. Just tested with gcc - not so!

Comment: floris how should i use ?: i cant find an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You evaluate `p+1` but you never store it in the variable `p`. Thus you never "walk along" the string and you never find the terminating character.

Evaluating `p+1` is not the same as `p++` (which evaluates p, then increments it and stores in back in p).

Also - you have a semicolon right after the `for` statement so you never execute anything after until the loop terminates. In other words, the `printf("%s%s",p,b);` statement is not part of the `for` loop (just in case you were wondering).

You could see this is true by changing you loop to:

```
char* x;
for (i = 0; i<5 ; i++, x=p+1) {
  printf("%s\n", x);
}
```

and see what happens:

```
ello
llo
lo
o
```

You would normally do something like this:

```
for (i = 0; *p != '\0' ; i++, p++) {
  printf("%s %s\n",p,b);
}
```

which gets you

```
Hello World
ello World
llo World
lo World
o World
```

Answer (score 0):

The comma operator in `i++, p+1` simply does both things, i.e. increments `i` then evaluates (but throws away the result of) `p+1`. Perhaps you meant `i++, p++`.